# Limit (in probability) of sequence of independent random variables

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

We have $\{X_n\}$ independent random variables which converge to $X$ in probability. I was asked to prove that $X$ is constant.

My approach is to try to show that$Var(X)=0 \implies X$ constant, but i have only been able to show the result when some $X_n$ or $X$ has finite variation.

Is the result trivial? I've already lost a whole evening trying to prove it.

Comment: That is trivial, my question is about how to show that elemnts on both sides of inequality are finite.

Answer (score 4):

Since $X_n\xrightarrow{p} X$ there exists a subsequence $X_{n_k}\xrightarrow{a.s.}X$. However, the event $\{X\le x\}=$$\{\lim X_{n_k}\le x\}$ is a tail event so that $X$ must be constant by Kolomogorov's $0-1$ law.

Comment: I know almost nothing from probability so be patient ;) I am aware of the first line. Than the equality of that sets is true but the rest is unknown to me ;)

Comment: 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov's_zero%E2%80%93one_law

Comment: 2. Tail event is an event measurable wrt the tail sigma algebra: $\tau=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \sigma(X_i,X_{i+1},...)$

Comment: 3. $P\{X\le x\}=0$ or $1$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. So it must be constant a.s.

Comment: Thanks, your approach is very instructive.